# Contar pessoas no Kinect - Skeleton ou DepthStream

Tags: c#, kinect

Como posso contar pessoas com o Kinect?

Já instalei o SDK, como tenho a versão 1 do Kinect estou com o SDK 1.8, peguei os exemplos do próprio Kinect Toolkit porém mesmo fuçando no código dos exemplos não achei um jeito de contar quantas pessoas o Kinect conseguiu enxergar.

Consegui saber o que acontece quando ele vê uma pessoa e quando ele não vê nenhuma, mas sabem como faço para pegar a quantidade de pessoas que ele está vendo?

Comment: A API do Kinect já tem um detector de faces desde a versão 1.5: http://www.computervisiononline.com/blog/microsoft-released-face-tracking-sdk-kinect-windows Mas eu li em algum lugar que o SDK está limitado no rastreamento de até 6 pessoas.

Comment: Mas dependendo do seu problema você pode usar uma webcam comum pra implementar o seu próprio contador de faces usando o algoritmo de Viola-Jones (Haar Cascade) já implementado no OpenCV (com portes para C++, Python, Java e Android - até onde eu sei): http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/py_tutorials/py_objdetect/py_face_detection/py_face_detection.html

Comment: Eu preciso mesmo da detecção por corpo mesmo pois ele deverá ver todos que estão em uma sala, ele ficará na parede próximo ao teto.

Tem que ser com o kinect pois é um projeto do trabalho.

Obrigado pela atenção :)

Comment: Por nada. Esse outro trabalho pode ajudar então: http://www.cbsr.ia.ac.cn/users/xczhang/paper/WaterFilling.pdf P.S.: Acho que é importante você editar a pergunta para colocar mais detalhes sobre o seu problema (incluindo o fato de que precisa usar o Kinect próximo ao teto). Vai ajudar a ter respostas mais precisas.

Comment: Muito antiga, restrita a um sdk e produto descontinuados